# Getting 404 error when hitting endpoint after MSAL Azure AD login

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js, azure-ad-msal

I am attempting to use the UserAgentApplication.loginPopup to validate users on our Azure AD. We are moving from an asp.net MVC application to a Vue.js front end and asp.net 'API' backend. My intention is to pass the accessToken from MSAL to our backend, then use it to validate access levels. When I run it locally, it works perfectly, but once I publish it to the server, I am getting a 404 error when hitting the '/api/authentication/SetAzureUser' endpoint.

## route.js

```
var myMSALObj;

const getLoginPopup = (request) => {
    return myMSALObj.loginPopup(request);
}

const getTokenPopup = (request) => {
    return myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request)
        .catch(() => {
            // fallback to interaction when the silent call fails
            return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request)
                .then(tokenResponse => {
                    return tokenResponse;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        });
}

const azureUserAuthentication = async () => {
    const utilityStore = useUtilityStore();

    try {
        const msalConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: "clientId",
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
                redirectUri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/api/authentication/AzureAuthenticationCallback`,
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
                storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you're having issues on Internet Explorer 11 or Edge
            }
        };

        const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ["openid", "profile", "User.Read.All"]
        };

        const tokenRequest = {
            scopes: ["Mail.Read"]
        };

        myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

        var loginPopupResponse = await getLoginPopup(loginRequest);

        if (loginPopupResponse != null && myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
            var tokenResponse = await getTokenPopup(tokenRequest);

            if (tokenResponse != null) {
                
                // Getting 404 on this axios call.
                var setAzureUserResponse = await axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: '/api/authentication/SetAzureUser',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    withCredentials: true,
                    params: {
                        accessToken: tokenResponse.accessToken
                    }
                });

                if (!setAzureUserResponse.succeeded) {
                    window.document.title = "Unauthorized Access";
                    return { name: 'unauthorized-access' }
                } else {
                    utilityStore.$patch({ showProcessingOverlay: false });
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

## API Endpoint

```
    [HttpGet("SetAzureUser")]
    public JsonResult SetAzureUser(string accessToken)
    {
        return Json(_authenticationService.AuthenticateAzureUser(_stateManagement.BuildBaseParameters(), accessToken));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing from loginPopUp to loginRedirect.